# How to show another link post from another blog multisite?

Tags: multisite

Is there any code or plugin to insert another link post from another blog multisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best and simple method to Insert / display articles from another site or multisite is to use wordpress inbuilt RSS Widget.

Or else you can try the following plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hungryfeed/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-retriever/

Hope this helps!